# Extreme Value Theorem for Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $S$ be a non empty closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and
>   let $f: S \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function on $S$, then there
>    exists $z_1,z_2 \in S$ such that $$f(z_1)\leq f(z) \leq f(z_2) ~~~
>  \forall z \in S$$
>
> In particular, the above means that there exists $M$ such that $|f(z)|
>  \leq M$ for all $z \in S$ and where equality holds for at least one
>   such $z$.

My proof is as follows:

Since $f$ is continuous, we have the fact that $u$ and $v$ are also continuous at every point in $S$. Hence we can deduce that $$|f(z)| = \sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}}$$
to be continuous throughout $S$. By the EVT for real analysis, we conclude that $|f(z)|$ reaches a maximum value $M$ somewhere in $S$.

Somehow i feel something is wrong with my last sentence, anyone can correct me or give me some insight will be appreciated.

Comment: What does $a\le b$ mean for complex numbers $a,b?$

Comment: Hmm i never thought of that as when there is a comparison, it is always with a modulus as complex numbers are vectors on the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vert f(z)\vert $ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so the ordinary extreme value theorem doesn't help, here. However, $S$ is compact (closed and bounded), and so since $\vert f \vert$ is continuous, the image of $S$ is compact.

Finally, every compact subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has a minimum and maximum, since because it is bounded below it has a supremum $a$ and infimum $b$. $a$ and $b$ are limit points of $A$, and so since $A$ is closed, we have $a,b\in A$, so $a$ and $b$ are the minimum and maximum of $A$, respectively.

Comment: Will there be a way to understand this without using the word compact? As compactness is something i have yet to touch upon, or rather, soon

Comment: You can just replace every instance of the word "compact" with "closed and bounded".